# weird behavior after modifying sortingnetworks cuda

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cuda

I need to modify the bitonic sort algorithm provided by this [CUDA Sorting Networks](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-sorting-networks). I have already modified it to accept float2 array of structs and all worked well until I added an extra uint variable in the kernels. I have also correctly modified the declaration of the functions where ever necessary but I am getting too much errors for no reason, at least from what I can tell... here is a part of a code:

```
__global__ void bitonicSortShared(
    float2 *d_P_out,
    float2 *d_P_in,
    uint arrayLength,
    uint dir,
    uint xy 
)
{//here gives the Error 2
    //Shared memory storage for one or more short vectors
    __shared__ float2 s_key[SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT];

    //Offset to the beginning of subbatch and load data
    d_P_in  += blockIdx.x * SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT + threadIdx.x;
    d_P_out += blockIdx.x * SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT + threadIdx.x;
    s_key[threadIdx.x +                       0] = d_P_in[                      0];
    s_key[threadIdx.x + (SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT / 2)] = d_P_in[(SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT / 2)];

    for (uint size = 2; size < arrayLength; size <<= 1){
        //Bitonic merge
        uint ddd = dir ^ ((threadIdx.x & (size / 2)) != 0);

        for (uint stride = size / 2; stride > 0; stride >>= 1) {
            __syncthreads();
            uint pos = 2 * threadIdx.x - (threadIdx.x & (stride - 1));
            Comparator( s_key[pos +  0], s_key[pos + stride], ddd, xy );
        }
    }

    //ddd == dir for the last bitonic merge step
    {
        for (uint stride = arrayLength / 2; stride > 0; stride >>= 1) {
            __syncthreads();
            uint pos = 2 * threadIdx.x - (threadIdx.x & (stride - 1));
            Comparator( s_key[pos +  0], s_key[pos + stride], dir, xy );
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();// here gives the Error 3 and so on
    d_P_out[                      0] = s_key[threadIdx.x +                       0];
    d_P_out[(SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT / 2)] = s_key[threadIdx.x + (SHARED_SIZE_LIMIT / 2)];
}
```

and the comparator function here:

```
__device__ inline void Comparator(
    float2 &keyA,
    float2 &keyB,
    uint dir,
    uint xy )
{
    float2 t;

    if (xy == 0){
        if ((keyA.x > keyB.x) == dir) {
            t = keyA;
            keyA = keyB;
            keyB = t;
        }
    } // I MISSED THAT and the error was reported in the other .cu file. :|
    else{
        if ((keyA.y > keyB.y) == dir) {
            t = keyA;
            keyA = keyB;
            keyB = t;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors dont make any sense, I have already checked over and over in case i forgot a parentheses or something but its all good.
Here are some errors:

```
Error   2   error : expected a ";"  E:\...bitonicSort.cu    27
Error   4   error : explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)    E:\...bitonicSort.cu    56
Error   5   error : cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone    E:\...bitonicSort.cu    56
Error   6   error : the size of an array must be greater than zero  E:\...bitonicSort.cu    57
Error   7   error : identifier "s_key" is undefined E:\...bitonicSort.cu    57
Error   8   error : this declaration has no storage class or type specifier E:\...bitonicSort.cu    58
Error   9   error : variable "d_P_out" has already been defined E:\...bitonicSort.cu    58
Error   10  error : initialization with "{...}" expected for aggregate object   E:\...bitonicSort.cu    58
Error   11  error : expected a declaration  E:\...bitonicSort.cu    59
Error   13  error : expected a declaration  E:\...bitonicSort.cu    98
Error   14  error : explicit type is missing ("int" assumed) E:\...bitonicSort.cu   105
```

I am using visual studio 2010 and windows 7. Thanks in advance for you time!

***EDIT*** The error was actually in the .cuh file that included the comparator function.  Feel free and vote to close the question if you want.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which is line 27 in bitonicSort.cu?

Comment: @talonmies You are right but, I cannot paste all the program here can I?

Comment: So how are we supposed to find your syntax error if you won't show the *relevent* (note that word) code? I have voted to close this, I can't see how it is possible to answer this question in its current form, and I don't see how anyone else will benefit from this question, or any answer to it....

Comment: @talonmies I will edit the question.

Comment: @talonmies Well I do not know where to ask for help since this seems a little weird. How can the program run fine but when i add one more parameter i get tons of errors? Is there any way that the author of the code has some sort of priviledge lock for this project or so?

Comment: Too lame question :| Feel sorry for that...

Comment: As a general rule, if you have a *syntax error*, you probably don't have a useful Stack Overflow question. But, if you had a question about the syntax or feature of a language, then you might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Comparator` function is preceding your `bitonicSortShared` function in your source file, and you don't have enough curly closing-braces at the end of your `Comparator` function.  Add one like so:

```
            keyB = t;
        }
    }
}
}   // add this curly close-brace
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for reply. The comparator function was in another file in `sortingNetworks_common.cuh` and yes that was the problem. Though i dont understand why it was showing error only on the `bitonicSort.cu` file. Is it a bug or something?

Comment: `sortingNetworks_common.cuh` was undoubtedly getting included at the beginning of your `bitonicSort.cu` so for all intents and purposes, it is as if the comparator function preceded the bitonicSort function in that file.  These questions are all about basic C programming methodology and have nothing to do with CUDA.    I don't see anything that resembles a bug other than the fact that you made a mistake in your code syntax.

Comment: Yeh the question is kinda lame. I did not know that errors would not be reported in the header file but in the file that was actually included. anyway thanks for answering though. I have voted to close this question.

Comment: A header file by itself is usually not compiled.  The compiler only "sees" the header file when it compiles a `.c`, `.cpp`, or `.cu` (or other compilable) file that includes the header.